# How can I use MongoDB query selectors in persistent-mongoDB? (Yesod)

Tags: mongodb, haskell, yesod

There is no any documentation or example in http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent

Also I didn't found any example of raw queries (apparently, **rawQuery** does't work with **persistent-mongoDB**).
I need to use geospecial selectors (**$near**), thats why I can't just call **selectList**.

However, there is a way to do something that I want with **Database.MongoDB**:

```
rawrecs <- runDB $ find (select 
["loc" =: [
  "$near" =: [ 
    "$geometry" =: [ 
      "type" =: ("Point"::String), 
      "coordinates" =: [ (28.483334::Double),(49.233334::Double) ] 
    ], 
    "$maxDistance" =: (1000::Int) 
  ] 
]] "points") { limit = 10 } >>= rest
mapM_ (liftIO . putStrLn . show) rawrecs
```

And then convert query results into persistent Entity.
Yep, it works, but it looks a bit tricky.

Does anyone know a more correct way to do this with persistent-mongoDB?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

a)

```
  { _id : ObjectId(...),
name : "...",
addresses : [ {
             context : "home" ,
             loc : [ 55.5, 42.3 ]
            } ,
            {
             context : "home",
             loc : [ -74 , 44.74 ]
            }
          ]
}
```

b)

```
db.records.ensureIndex( { "addresses.loc": "2d" } )
```

c)

```
db.places.find( { loc :
              { $geoWithin :
                { $geometry :
                  { type : "Polygon" ,
                    coordinates : [ [
                                      [ 0 , 0 ] ,
                                      [ 3 , 6 ] ,
                                      [ 6 , 1 ] ,
                                      [ 0 , 0 ]
                                    ] ]
            } } } } )
```

For more information you can go to

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes-geo/

I am not very much expert but I hope that my answer can help you...

Comment: Oh, I know how to perform queries with geospecial selectors, the main problem is in compability with mongodb driver for haskell (persistent-mongoDB). I have added a real-life example, just in case. But thanks anyway :)